# Styling react-select with styled-components

Tags: styled-components, react-select

I'm trying to change the color of the select-up-arrow and the color of the control when it's in focus, but without success. Have anyone done this using styled-components?

Answer (score 7):

### This applies to react-select@v3.*

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

`CustomSelect.js` file:

```js
import ReactSelect from 'react-select';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const CustomSelect = styled(ReactSelect)`
  & .Select__indicator Select__dropdown-indicator {
    border-color: transparent transparent red;
  }
`;
```

`TheComponent.js` file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { CustomSelect } from './CustomSelect';

export function TheComponent () {
  return <div>
           <CustomSelect
             classNamePrefix={'Select'}
             {* props... *}
           />
           Something awesome here...
         </div>
} 
`;
```

Note the `classNamePrefix={'Select'}` in `TheComponent.js` - that's important.

Answer (score 6):

#### This applies to `react-select@v2.*`

The same ideas as @bamse answer can be applied to v2 of react-select. The problem is that in v2 they removed pre-determined class names unless you specify to add them in with the prop `classNamePrefix`. They also changed what the class names in general look like.

General solution is to make sure to add in the class names with the prop `classNamePrefix`, then use styled around ReactSelect and target classes within it.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactSelect from 'react-select';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const ReactSelectElement = styled(ReactSelect)`
  .react-select__indicator react-select__dropdown-indicator {
    border-color: transparent transparent red;
  }
`;

export (props) => <ReactSelectElement classNamePrefix="react-select" {...props} />
```

Answer (score 1):

#### This applies to `react-select@v1.*`

[Here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1679#issuecomment-307016615) you can find an example of styling `react-select` with `styled-components`.

To change to caret's colour when the select is opened you can use this

```
&.Select.is-open > .Select-control .Select-arrow {
  border-color: transparent transparent red;
}
```

The component would look like

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactSelect from 'react-select';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const RedCaretWhenOpened = styled(ReactSelect)`
  &.Select.is-open > .Select-control .Select-arrow {
    border-color: transparent transparent red;
  }
`;

export (props) => <RedCaretWhenOpened {...props} />
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it 